# How to implement generic lambda with default arguments?

Tags: c++, lambda, default-arguments

Boiled down example of what I wanted to do:

```
auto callable = [](auto x, auto y = 0){return x + y;};
```

On it's own it compiles, and `callable(1, 2)` works as expected, but `callable(3)` gives a compilation error:

```
error: no match for call to '(f()::<lambda(auto:1, auto:2)>) (int)'
```

This is not an issue with lambdas specifically, same thing happens with generic functions with default argument
If `callable` was a function (template), then `callable<int, int>(3)` would work
For lambdas this workaround becomes a bit uglier:
`callable.operator()<int, int>(3)`

What I originally thought would happen under the hood:

```
struct Callable {
    auto operator()(auto x, auto y){return x + y;}
    auto operator()(auto x){return this->operator()(x, 0);}
};
```

As in, I was expecting the lambda to behave like `Callable{}`
And `Callable callable;` is nice regarding the mentioned behaviour, both `callable(1, 2)` and `callable(3)` compile
This "unraveled" lambda-esque struct solution could work for my case, but I have some issues with it:

1. My actual use for this is significantly more complicated than the boiled down example, and trying to use the struct solution would be a PITA
2. I'm using C++20, the solution doesn't feel very modern, aesthetically it reminds me of emulating C++20 functionalities in C++11

To sum this up:

1. I want an object `callable`
2. I want the expression `callable(a, b)` to compile to user-specified implementation
   In the example above the implementation was `return a + b;` but I obviously don't care about addition specifically
3. `callable(a, b)` should be generic, meaning it should be invokable with various types of arguments (as long as the user-specified implementation permits it)
4. I want the expression `callable(a)` to compile and to be equivalent to `callable(a, 0)`
5. `callable(a)` should again be generic
6. I STRONGLY prefer solutions in which `callable` is a lambda

If I remove the requirements (4) and (5) this is trivially doable with a lambda

[All examples mentioned on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rqfPPG87c)

NOTE: default arguments with lambdas work if they aren't generic `[](int x, int y = 0){return x+y;}`

Tried generic lambda, didn't work
Tried generic function, didn't work
Tried unrolled lambda via struct, works but not that great

Comment: This is effectively a template, and in C++ types of template parameters cannot be deduced from their default values. See the duplicate question for more information.

Comment: Bit of a mess and requites C++20:  `auto callable = []<class T, class U=decltype(0)>(T x, U y = 0){return x + y;};` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/xE4e4jPoc
`

Comment: Richard Critten: your solution is good, would accept